# Filter on same value in a column according to a serie of same value in one column

Tags: sql

I have this data (see screenshot attached). I want to consider appointment series for which all
appointments in the serie have the exact same visit_motive_id. I mean that for appointment_set_id=337438750, I only want to keep one visit_motive_id, keeping in mind that sometimes you can have the same visit_motive_id for different appointment_set_id.

This is how the my data looks like

```
+--------------------+-----------------+
| appointment_set_id | visit_motive_id |
+--------------------+-----------------+
|          336926466 |          388468 |
|          336926466 |          388468 |
|          337145347 |           69664 |
|          337438750 |          484259 |
|          337438750 |          484259 |
|          337438750 |          484261 |
|          337438750 |          484262 |
|          337652969 |            1725 |
|          337652969 |            1725 |
|          337652969 |            1726 |
|          337652969 |            1727 |
|          337652969 |            1725 |
|          337652969 |            1725 |
+--------------------+-----------------+
```

This is what I need to have, one single visit_motive_id for an appointment_set_id.

```
+--------------------+-----------------+
| appointment_set_id | visit_motive_id |
+--------------------+-----------------+
|          336926466 |          388468 |
|          336926466 |          388468 |
|          337145347 |           69664 |
|          337438750 |          484259 |
|          337438750 |          484259 |
|          337652969 |            1725 |
|          337652969 |            1725 |
|          337652969 |            1725 |
|          337652969 |            1725 |
+--------------------+-----------------+
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not images.

Comment: Please show us the result that you expect.

Comment: How do you choose among the multiple values when there is more than one motive?

Comment: I need to exclude all appointment_set_id that have more than one visit_motive_id. The query of @The Impaler works . However, it excludes the case when appointment_set_id is null

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HAVING` to filter out the appointments that have multiple visits. For example:

```
select * 
from t
where appointment_set_id is null 
   or appointment_set_id in (
      select appointment_set_id
      from t
      group by appointment_set_id
      having min(visit_motive_id) <> max(visit_motive_id)
    )
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! However, sometimes I have appointment_set_id which can be null and this excludes this possibility. What could be done ?

Comment: @poofidoudou `null` is not a value, but the *absence* of value, so it doesn't represent an `appointment_set_id`. Does it?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! null shows that the appointments is not part of a serie ! I need to take into account such case

Comment: @poofidoudou Fixed. Since "null shows that the appointments is not part of a serie", then all `null` values are separate appointments, and now all of them are included.

Answer (score 0):

You can do aggregation :

```
select appointment_set_id, visit_motive_id
from table t
group by appointment_set_id, visit_motive_id
having count(*) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

i suspect you want the most frequent "motive".  This is technically called the "mode".  Aggregation and window functions does this:

```
select appointment_set_id, visit_motive_id
from (select appointment_set_id, visit_motive_id, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by appointment_set_id order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by appointment_set_id, visit_motive_id
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This does not return the original rows.  But that does not actually seem useful.  You can, of course, use `join` or a similar mechanism to get the original rows.